# How to query substring in a string in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

How to query substring in a string in python sqlite3?

I am using this:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM customers where instr(FirstName,'Le')")
This works fine but I want to search for user input like this:
ss=(some_user_Entry).get()
cur.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM customers where instr(FirstName,ss)")
```

but it wont work

what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement and bind the user input's value to your query:

```py
ss = (some_user_Entry).get()
cur.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM customers WHERE INSTR(FirstName, ?)", (ss,))
```